# Why does deque::erase() invoke assignment operator?

Tags: c++, c++11, deque

Just as the title says, why does deque invoke the assignment operator of the contained type during erase()? I can understand why vector might because elements in a vector are in contiguous memory, but since deque doesn't guarantee contiguous memory, why would it try to move its elements around when some of its elements are removed.

This code fails to compile because my `Contained` type's assignment operator is deleted and it doesn't have a move constructor.

```
#include <deque>

class Contained
{
public:
    Contained() = default;
    ~Contained() { }
    Contained(const Contained&) = delete;
    Contained& operator=(const Contained&) = delete;
};

class Container
{
public:
    Container()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { m_containerDS.emplace_back(); }
    }

    ~Container() { }

    void clear() 
    { 
        m_containerDS.erase(m_containerDS.begin(), m_containerDS.end()); 
    }

private:
    std::deque<Contained> m_containerDS;
};


int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

The MSVC compiler emits this error message:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xutility(2527): error C2280: 'Contained &Contained::operator =(const Contained &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function
1>          ConsoleApplication13.cpp(12) : see declaration of 'Contained::operator ='
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xutility(2548) : see reference to function template instantiation '_BidIt2 std::_Move_backward<_BidIt1,_BidIt2>(_BidIt1,_BidIt1,_BidIt2,std::_Nonscalar_ptr_iterator_tag)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _BidIt2=std::_Deque_iterator<std::_Deque_val<std::_Deque_simple_types<Contained>>>
1>  ,            _BidIt1=std::_Deque_iterator<std::_Deque_val<std::_Deque_simple_types<Contained>>>
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\deque(1622) : see reference to function template instantiation '_BidIt2 std::_Move_backward<std::_Deque_iterator<std::_Deque_val<std::_Deque_simple_types<Contained>>>,std::_Deque_iterator<std::_Deque_val<std::_Deque_simple_types<Contained>>>>(_BidIt1,_BidIt1,_BidIt2)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _BidIt2=std::_Deque_iterator<std::_Deque_val<std::_Deque_simple_types<Contained>>>
1>  ,            _BidIt1=std::_Deque_iterator<std::_Deque_val<std::_Deque_simple_types<Contained>>>
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\deque(1601) : while compiling class template member function 'std::_Deque_iterator<std::_Deque_val<std::_Deque_simple_types<Contained>>> std::deque<Contained,std::allocator<_Ty>>::erase(std::_Deque_const_iterator<std::_Deque_val<std::_Deque_simple_types<_Ty>>>,std::_Deque_const_iterator<std::_Deque_val<std::_Deque_simple_types<_Ty>>>)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Contained
1>          ]
1>          ConsoleApplication13.cpp(27) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Deque_iterator<std::_Deque_val<std::_Deque_simple_types<Contained>>> std::deque<Contained,std::allocator<_Ty>>::erase(std::_Deque_const_iterator<std::_Deque_val<std::_Deque_simple_types<_Ty>>>,std::_Deque_const_iterator<std::_Deque_val<std::_Deque_simple_types<_Ty>>>)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Contained
1>          ]
1>          ConsoleApplication13.cpp(31) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::deque<Contained,std::allocator<_Ty>>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Contained
1>          ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: because

> Type requirements
>
> -T must meet the requirements of MoveAssignable.

Long answer: even though `std::deque` doesn't have a requirement to provide contiguous memory, it still has a requirement to provide a *constant* complextity `operator[]`. This is why it has to move elements.

Comment: I can make a container with constant complexity `operator[]` that does not use MoveAssignable on erase.  (examine `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>` with a layer that hides the unique_ptr from the end user).  So no, that is not why.

Comment: @Yakk, with meeting all other criteria as well? For random types? Can you please share your implementation, i'd very keen to see it. (And of course, without an extra indirection on every element access implied by pointer)

Comment: The easiest solution would be to take `std::deque<std::unique_ptr<T>>`.  Wrap insert with a call to `make_unique<T>`, and dereference with an extra `*`, and do some extra work when you copy or assign it (where you copy the contained object, not the ptr).  Mechanical, but what am I missing?  (doing it with a vector takes a bit more work, as you need to make it a doubly-ended vector and mess around with some other details)

Comment: @Yakk, see my edit - pointers are not a solution due to extra indirection and all it's perils. I doubt it runs counter of the letter of standard, but it certainly runs counter to it's spirit.

Comment: @SergeyA - I don't think a `deque` that uses an extra pointer indirection to access elements necessarily runs counter to the spirit of the standard.  However, the standard's requirements allow implementations  to *not* use that indirect access to elements.  However, prior to C++11, elements had to be CopyConstructable and Assignable anyway in order to put items in a container. When moving to C++11 the committee may have used the MoveAssignable requirement on certain `deque` operations so that implementations would be allowed to continue to use the core of their existing `deque` design.

Comment: @MichaelBurr, I believe, building pointers into default `deque` would kill cache locality (right now tranditional `deque` implementations have good cache locality). A deque without cache locality would be a deal-breaker for me and many of my collegues. If one wants a deque with pointers, one can just use it explicitly. To remain a generally useful container, general deque should not introduce indidrection where none was required before.

Comment: @SergeyA: I think that good cache locality could still be maintained with some work.  There's nothing that says that the element allocations would have to be completely separate - they could still be done in contiguous blocks. It might make for an interesting experiment to see if this can be done without killing the cache locality of the `deque`.

Answer (score 4):

This is because std::deque very often implemented as a ring buffer, which in its turn often implemented as single-piece memory buffer. That means when you remove elements from the deque it may need to move some elements if erased elements are not at either the end or the beginning of the sequence.
Here is the illustration:

```
    V buffer begins here                    V buffer ends here
1. [ ] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [ ] [ ] [ ]
        ^first element          ^last element

2. [ ] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [.] [ ] [ ] [ ]
                ^ you want to remove this element.

                <= these elements should be moved
                    V   V   V   V
3. [ ] [.] [.] [ ] [:] [:] [:] [:] [ ] [ ] [ ]
                ^ element have been removed.
```

Actually assignment operator only used if there is no move operator for the type. So if you add to your class the following line then everything compiles just fine:

```
Contained& operator=(Contained&&) = default;
```

**UPDATE:**
It seems I was wrong as the most of the STL implementations now use some variants of the [Dynamic Arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array#Variants), not ring buffers. Still, they are arrays and there is need to move elements if an element removed from the middle of the array.

Comment: Can you give an example of an implementation of `std` which implements `deque` as a ring buffer?

Comment: @Yakk, yeah, I'd like to see it too. Looks very intriguing.

Comment: @Yakk It seems I was wrong as the most of the STL implementations now use some variants of the [Dynamic Arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array#Variants), not ring buffers. Still, they are arrays and there is need to move elements if an element removed from the middle of them.